# On making a tooltip when the mouse comes out there is a

Tags: javascript, hover, tooltip

First, sorry I can not speak English well.
i'm lived south korea. T.T
This article is the question you used the Google translator.

http://jsfiddle.net/pagefact/xxdh9vmt/

```
$('.tool_pid a').hover(function() {
        var tip = $(this).attr('title');
        var cuf = $(this).data('cuf');
        var eva = $(this).data('eva');
        $(this).attr('title','');
        $(this).data('cuf','');
        $(this).data('eva','');
        $(this).append("<div id='tip' style='position:absolute;top:-80px;left:-14px;'><strong>"+ tip +"</strong><p class='stat'> CUF : "+ cuf + "<br />eva : "+ eva + "</p></div>");
        $("#tip")
            .css("position","relative")
           // .css("margin-left","0px")
           // .css("margin-top","-32px")
           // .css("display","block")
            .css("z-index","999")
            //.fadeIn("slow");
            .slideDown("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('title',$('#tip').html());
        $(this).children('div#tip').remove();
    });
```

---

stockoverflow I made reference to the source
Hover your mouse over the image title, cuf, eva is to come
When posting images per cuf, eva continues to be an additional

Are what's wrong is this?

Answer (score 0):

'data' and 'attr' is different from the script
so:

```
$(this).attr('title','');
$(this).attr('cuf','');
$(this).attr('eva','');
```

Should be:

```
$(this).attr('title','');
$(this).data('cuf','');
$(this).data('eva','');
```

Comment: Oh ... with it should not T.T